# Getting data from Scale serial port without <CR>

Tags: java, string, serial-port

Im trying to read the weight from a scale using the serial port.
But i think i'm receiving data with  and i don't know how to print it without the

My serial event:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
        switch(event.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
                outputBufferEmpty(event);
                break;

            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];
                try {
                     int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                     String str = new String (readBuffer, "UTF-8");
                     ok+=str;
                     //System.out.print(str);
                     System.out.println();
                     System.out.print(ok.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                     //System.out.print(str.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {}
                break;

        } 
    }
```

I tried all.
But this is my output now:

```
0
0                 0
0                 0                 0
0                 0                 0                 .
0                 0                 0                 .                 0
0                 0                 0                 .                 0                 5
0                 0                 0                 .                 0                 5                 0
0                 0                 0                 .                 0                 5                 0
```

And I want this:
 000.050 KG

This is the protocol of my scale:

[image: Scale Protocol]

For more information my scale is: Mettler Toledo VIVA or an OHAUS RV Series

Comment: To start, you should only create your string from the bytes that were really read, not just your entire 20-byte array: `new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8")`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I f&//("" Love you. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is:

You created a string from the entire 20-byte byte array, rather than the portion that you just read.

Change the line that creates the string to:

```
String str = new String(readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8")
```

The extra gaps in your output were probably caused by the null-bytes from the end of the array, although it's hard to know for sure without details on what type of output device you were using (not that important)

Comment: But now, you know how I can convert this string to Double?


`System.out.print(new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8"));` Output: `000.250` Good                

`m_dWeightBuffer = Double.parseDouble(peso);
System.out.print(m_dWeightBuffer);` Output: `0.00.0220.0` Bad

Answer (score 2):

Why dont u try to make it directly to double?

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Comment: How is this going to interpret an "**ASCII** 8 bytes string"?